# How do I make a div draggable from only a small part?

Tags: reactjs, drag-and-drop, react-dnd

I want to be able to drag the elements only from the dots in the left. Is it possible?

[image]

Comment: Take a look at this official example http://react-dnd.github.io/react-dnd/examples/customize/handles-and-previews

Answer (score 0):

There is a case for this exact functionality in the docs
http://react-dnd.github.io/react-dnd/examples/customize/handles-and-previews